# c - When specify O_APPEND and O_TRUNC together, it won't truncate?

Tags: c, file-io

As the title, when specify `O_APPEND` and `O_TRUNC` together, the file is not truncated first when open.

So, when specify `O_APPEND`, how can I still truncate the file first?

---

**@Update:**

`O_APPEND` and `O_TRUNC` do work together perfectly, it's my mistake in my previous code.

---

**About atomic**

Following code proves `O_APPEND` will make sure append operation in each `write()` is atomic, by setting offset to end automatically within an atomical system call.

```
// atomic append
// TLPI exercise 5.3

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int atomic_append(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *buf = "a";
    int opt;
    if(argc < 3) {
        printf("command format: %s\n", "atomic_append <filename> <byte-count> [x]");
        return -1;
    }
    char *fp = argv[1];
    int bc = atoi(argv[2]);
    int flag_append = 1;

    if(argc >=4 && strcmp(argv[3], "x")==0) {
        flag_append = 0;
    }

    int fd = open(fp, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | (flag_append?O_APPEND:0), 0644);
    int i=0;
    while(i++ < bc) {
        if(!flag_append)  {
            lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END); 
        }
        write(fd, buf, 1);
    }
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    atomic_append(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Steps to compile and run:

- Compile it as `a.out`
- `./a.out a1 100000 & ./a.out a1 100000`
- `./a.out a2 100000 x & ./a.out a2 100000 x`
- `ll -h a*`

Then you can see a1 and a2 has different size.
This is an exercise from TLPI exercise 5.3.

Comment: What file access mode are you specifying?

Comment: That's the file creation permission bits. Which one of `O_RDWR`, `O_RDONLY`, etc?

Comment: @Mat Here is what I use `int fd = open(fp, O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0644);`

Comment: O_APPEND and O_TRUNC are mutually exclusive.  and (as chearly shown in your code, O_APPEND 'trumps' O_TRUNC   Suggest:  make up your mind as to which you want the code to do and implement accordingly.

Comment: With fopen() use mode "w".   with open() use O_TRUNC and remove the O_APPEND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`O_APPEND` and `O_TRUNC` work fine together. If they don't I would suspect a bug in your operating system (or more likely in your code).

Here's a simple test program, this works fine on both MacOS, OpenBSD and two different versions of Linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <err.h>

#define FN "truncateme"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[16];
    ssize_t r;
    int fd;

    if ((fd = open(FN, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0600)) == -1)
        err(1, "open 1 ");

    if (write(fd, "foo", 3) != 3)
        err(1, "write 1");

    close(fd);

    if ((fd = open(FN, O_RDWR|O_TRUNC|O_APPEND, 0600)) == -1)
        err(1, "open 2");

    if (write(fd, "1", 1) != 1)
        err(1, "write 2");

    close(fd);

    if ((fd = open(FN, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
        err(1, "open 3");

    if ((r = read(fd, buf, 16)) != 1)
        errx(1, "read %d != 1", (int)r);

    return 0;
}
```

[Here is the POSIX description of `open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) Notice how it says "Any combination of the following may be used" and that list includes both `O_APPEND` and `O_TRUNC`.

I really don't see how `O_TRUNC` would in any way interact with `O_APPEND` since the first one just tells the operating system what to do with the file at the time of the opening, while `O_APPEND` tells the operating system what to do when calling the `write` and `writev` functions.

Also, to clear up the confusion the other answers gave you. [`O_APPEND` does guarantee atomicity of the write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html): "If the O_APPEND flag of the file status flags is set, the file offset shall be set to the end of the file prior to each write and no intervening file modification operation shall occur between changing the file offset and the write operation."

And to eliminate further confusion I've seen in the comments about atomicity of file operations under POSIX, [this part of the standard is relevant.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_07)

Comment: Your code works perfectly on my system, it's my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The file will be truncated if you specify both `O_TRUNC` and `O_APPEND` (at least on Linux):

```
// test.cc
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND);
}
```

Here's the example that shows that the file is truncated:

```
$ echo 'abc' > test.txt
$ g++ test.cc
$ ./a.out
$ cat test.txt
# no output here
```

Answer (score -1):

`O_APPEND` doesn't guarantee atomic writes. If you are using open/close/read/write, rather than stdio, there is no thread safety guaranteed.  If you are on Linux, I suspect that a write of exactly the number of bytes you request IS atomic, but, there is no specification that requires that.  If `write()` returns less than the requested size, there is no guarantee that the data in your next write (the rest of the buffer) is guaranteed to go after the first partial write.

I would strongly suggest you read up on mutexes or other locking mechanisms if you want to have a multi-threaded application produce output in the order you request if all are writing to the file.

Comment: Within a single `write()` it is atomic for sure, because all system calls are atomic. And, I havent learn to use `mutex` or `locking` yet, that will be in my future plan.

Comment: This is incorrect. `O_APPEND` does guarantee atomic writes. From POSIX: "If the O_APPEND flag of the file status flags is set, the file offset shall be set to the end of the file prior to each write and no intervening file modification operation shall occur between changing the file offset and the write operation."

Comment: @Art, With the example given (write(1)  != 1 being an error, you are correct, however, write() is not guaranteed to write out all the data (yes, it usually does).  For a non-blocking connection, it may return less than the requested amount.  If you are trying to write 32K, and you only write 30K, a second write will be needed to push out the remainder.  Two writes are not atomic.  The design should account for this (he didn't indicate blocking vs. non-blocking I/O).

Comment: @digger As far as I'm aware, non-blocking I/O to regular files (the only case where `O_TRUNC` makes sense) is not implemented by anyone, POSIX leaves it as unspecified. Other file handles have other semantics, pipes only guarantee atomicity below 512 (or was it 256?) bytes, sockets never guarantee anything, etc. But for regular files, you will not get short writes unless there's a real error (EINTR has all-or-nothing semantics in POSIX).